# How to find where meteor is installed in windows?

Tags: meteor

I have installed meteor on my windows 10 and I am unable to find the folder which contains it as well as the "simple-todos" app which it installs for tutorial.

Where are they?

Comment: you only need to type "meteor" in your file explorer and wait for a while before you get an answer. But instead you typed out a question.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor stores its files on Windows in the folder AppData/Local/.meteor.
You can easily get there by typing %appdata%/../Local/.meteor in Windows' Run (Win+R) or in File Explorer's Address Bar.

To get to your todos app, it should be in C:\Users\(User)\todos.